# When does `git push` go through when git push triggers auto packing?

Tags: git, git-push, packing

Suppose I push a commit to `git`. It reports something like the following:

```
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
Counting objects: 56, done. 
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done. 
Writing objects: 100%
(56/56), 2.14 MiB | 3.81 MiB/s, done. Total 56 (delta 16), reused 0
(delta 0) Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
```

I know I should let `git` do its thing for better optimization. Suppose I ran out of patience and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to kill the process *during* the "Auto packing" step.

**Did the `git push` complete?** If so, at which step?

Related: 
Why would `git` do the packing *now*, during a push? Why not, when `git` detects that a packing is necessary, display a helpful message to the user -- something like:

```
Git: Your repository size may be causing inefficiency. 

Please pack the repository at your earliest convenience by running the following:

    git pack
```

Comment: "Why would git do the packing now, during a push?" -- First thought is that the message is coming from the remote. The message comes immediately after it receives the new objects that make a pack worthwhile. You seem to have the impression that the pack is running locally (otherwise your idea of suggesting running `git pack` manually doesn't make sense), but have you been able to verify that?

Comment: @hvd: If the message came from the remote, it would be prefixed with `remote:`. It's true that by default, receive-pack runs `git gc --auto`, but it runs it with `--quiet` so that you don't see that. The *really* odd thing here is that `git push` *doesn't* run `git gc --auto`—only `am`, `fetch`, `merge`, `receive-pack`, and two scripts (`rebase` and a Perl SVN script) do that.

Answer (score 1):

> Did the git push complete? If so, at which step?

I don't know for certain, but it seems very likely that it finished pushing the commits to the remote when it reported that it was done with compressing and writing:

```
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done. 
Writing objects: 100%
(56/56), 2.14 MiB | 3.81 MiB/s, done. Total 56 (delta 16), reused 0
```

> Why would git do the packing now, during a push? Why not, when git detects that a packing is necessary, display a helpful message to the user

Because people either never ran it and instead complained that git was slow, or ran it all the time in every repo just in case (and so wasted time).